# Declare a var of type Stripe charge create outside try catch

Tags: c#, asp.net, stripe-payments

I have the following Payments code.

```
var service = new StripeChargeService(newgenSecretKey);
try
{
     var result = service.Create(newCharge);

    if (result.Paid)
    {
        lab.Text = "It worked";
        CartOrders.UpdateTransactionID(result.Id, OrderID, "Express Checkout");

        Response.Redirect("PgeCustSuccess.aspx?OrderID=" + OrderID);

    }
}
catch (StripeException stripeException)
{
    Debug.WriteLine(stripeException.Message);
    stripe.Text = stripeException.Message;
    //CartOrders.UpdateTransactionID(result.FailureMessage, OrderID, "Express Checkout");    
}
```

I would like to log the commented out value in the catch block(result.FailureMessage).I am trying to catch the Stripe Errors if thrown and logging it into my database. The problem I am facing is that I cannot get the result.FailureMessage to work in the catch block. I understand that a global var cannot be declared and must only be used locally.

Here are a few thing that I tried.

Declared the result outside the try block but did not succeed because var should be initialised with a type and it is of type stripe

```
var service = new StripeChargeService(newgenSecretKey);
var result = new { };
try
{
    //did not work
    result = service.Create(newCharge);

    if (result.Paid)
    {
```

Any Ideas ?

Comment: If the variable needs to be used outside the `try` block then it needs to be declared outside the `try` block but, as with any variable, you need to declare it as the type it is meant to be.  The fact that you must initialise it inside the `try` block is irrelevant to where you declare it.  They are two different things.  If the return type of `service.Create` is `Stripe` then that's the type you declare the `result variable as: `Stripe result;`.  You would need to test whether `result` is `null` before using it in the `catch` block.  You may also have to initialise it as `null`.

Comment: 'StripeChargeService' is a type but it calls the create new charge. So I am not able to declare it

Comment: It returns a charge object. But how would i specify it as a type ?

Comment: @jmcilhinney. Figured it out . Your comment was really helpful. Could you write an answer so that I can mark it as correct. I declared the result variable as         var result = (Stripe.StripeCharge)null;   and it works as expected

Answer (score 0):

You could do:

```
var service = new StripeChargeService(newgenSecretKey);
Stripe result;
try
{
   result = service.Create(newCharge);
   if (result.Paid)
   {
```

Comment: This answer is not useful. Stripe is a namespace and not a type

Comment: What does service.Create Type return? It has to return a Type of object. If the namespace and the type are the same, try using a namespace alias for the Type. Worst case (though I'd avoid this) you could use the dynamic keyword

Comment: Now its working. it returns  a stripe charge object. All I did was declare it ourside as    var result = (Stripe.StripeCharge)null    .

Answer (score 0):

Try moving result up out of the try, or:

```
var service = new StripeChargeService(newgenSecretKey);
var result;

try
{
 result = service.Create(newCharge);

if (result.Paid)
{
    lab.Text = "It worked";
    CartOrders.UpdateTransactionID(result.Id, OrderID, "Express Checkout");

    Response.Redirect("PgeCustSuccess.aspx?OrderID=" + OrderID);

  }
}
catch (StripeException stripeException)
{
    Debug.WriteLine(stripeException.Message);
    stripe.Text = stripeException.Message;
    //CartOrders.UpdateTransactionID(result.FailureMessage, OrderID, "Express Checkout");    
}
```

Note that your result.FailureMessage may throw an Exception if result is never populated;  you could use an if statement or try-catch to prevent against this.

Comment: Same way I thought would work. Unfortunately in c#, a var should be initialised with a value when declared. The compile fails when I try to allocate it dynamically as well

Comment: Couldn't you initialize it to nil?

Comment: Cannot assign null to an implicitly typed variable

Comment: How about explicitly?  What's the type of result?